# How to concatenate and sort three CSV files in Gnuplot

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I have to plot with Gnuplot the data contained in 3 CSV files.

Commonly, I use the following code to plot from 2 CSV files:

```
$datablock << EOD
`cat ../Q1a/sim_Q1.csv <(tail -n+8 ../Q1b/sim_Q1.csv | tr '",' '  ' | sort -nk19 )| tail -n+8  | tr '",' '  ' | sort -nk19 > ../Q1a/Q6_ressult.txt`
EOD
set print "|bash -x"
print $datablock
set print
```

The CSVs are in three different directories.
The data start at row 8, and I must take out the `"` and `,` characters, and sort the data by column 19.

I do not know how to extend this code to paste 3 different CSV's doing the same, `sort`, `tail -n+8` and `tr` commands, and get a final `.txt` file with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Gnuplot plays into this specifically, but if you're looking for a way to `tail` multiple files you can do so simply by passing their names on the command line.

The only gotcha is that `tail` will separate the outputs with a header for easier human viewing unless you add the `-q` option:

> ```
>    -q, --quiet, --silent
>           never output headers giving file names
> ```

So as far I can see, you can skip the process substitutions and multiple (re)sorts simply do

```
tail -q -n+8 ../Q1a/sim_Q1.csv ../Q1b/sim_Q1.csv ../Q1c/sim_Q1.csv | tr '",' '  ' | sort -nk19
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code is simple and works fine. I would like to ask you how could I select a range of rows in the second file, for example from the 8 row to the 470 row. I could use `sed -n -e '8,470p'` , but I do not know how to change your solution. I think the problem is that I need this range selection in just one of the three files.

Comment: @user1993416 probably the simplest modification would be `tail -q -n+8 file1 <(head -n 470 file2) file3`

Comment: Finally, my results are in 5 files and 2 of them, I have to make the `head -n` until some row. Can I write something like `tail -q -n+8 file1 <(head -n470 file2 <(head -n380 file3)) file4 file5` ?

Comment: I have posted a new question with the paste of the 5 files. Regards.