# How to concatenate several CSV files avoiding some lines at the beginning and in some at the end

Tags: shell, csv

I would like to join 5 CSV files. 
In all of them, the data starts at the 8th row.
In two of them, I want to take out some lines at the end of the file.

From my precedent question ["How to concatenate and sort three CSV files in Gnuplot"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499820/how-to-paste-and-sort-three-csv-files-in-gnuplot/499848?noredirect=1#comment920680_499848)
 I know how to make it with 3 files and with one of which I select some rows with `head` command.

```
tail -q -n+8 file1 <(head -n 470 file2) file3
```

However, I have 5 files, and in 2 I want to select the number of data rows.
How could I make this?. 
I want to execute this code inside a Gnuplot script.

NOTE:
In the following [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/le4aisizmfbrrmz/AACABYGr4M0CvYwKviihY8-2a?dl=0) there are 5 CSV example files. In file5.csv I would like to not concatenate the last 10 lines and in file3.csv not concatenate the last 8 rows.

Regards

Comment: The verbs "paste" and "join" have specific meanings.  "Pasting" (using the `paste` utility) adds files side by side (adding columns).  "Joining" is a relational operation (used with the `join` utility or in relational databases) whereby you match the data in a particular column between two files. You seem to be talking about "concatenation", i.e. concatenating (adding) data to the end of other data. Is that correct?

Comment: @Kusalananda You are right. I want to join and match columns from different files. English is not my mother tongue:-)

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry I meant to say 'concatenation' not joining.

Comment: Instead of specifying where the data starts show us an example of the data and we may be able to automate that part

Comment: @Kusalananda Ok. I can post a link with 5 CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail -q -n+8 file1 file2 file3 <(head -n 470 file4) <(head -n 123 file5)
```